# Dynamic Accordion in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I used the Bootstrap v4.0.0 accordion to display my business services. Further, I created a custom post type "service" for my services (Each service is a post).

To display my services dynamically and not hardcode them, I implemented a for-loop within the WordPress while-loop which uses an enumeration to provide the number of the collapsible.

I don't like my solution, especially the enumeration - Is there a better way to solve this?
If you see any other improvement, I would be glad to hear also.

See my code below:

```
<div class="wv-archive-container wv-boxed-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <h1 id="wv-archive-header-h1">All Services</h1>
                <div id="wv-accordion" class="wv-accordion">
                    <div class="card mb-0">

                        <?php $wv_services = new WP_Query( array(
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'post_type'      => 'service',
                            'orderby'        => 'date',
                            'order'          => 'ASC'
                        ) );

                        while ( $wv_services->have_posts() ) {

                            $enum_of_collapsible_str_numbers = [
                                "One",
                                "Two",
                                "Three",
                                "Four",
                                "Five",
                                "Six",
                                "Seven",
                                "Eight",
                                "Nine",
                                "Ten",
                                "Eleven",
                                "Twelve",
                                "Thirtenn",
                                "Fourteen",
                                "Fivteen",
                                "Sixteen",
                                "Seventeen",
                                "Eighteen",
                                "Nineteen",
                                "Twenty"
                            ];
                            $total_number_of_service_posts = wp_count_posts('service')->publish;
                            for ($collapsible_str_number = 0; $collapsible_str_number < $total_number_of_service_posts; $collapsible_str_number++) {

                                $wv_services->the_post(); ?>

                                <div class="card-header collapsed" style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="collapse"
                                     href="#collapse<?php echo $enum_of_collapsible_str_numbers[$collapsible_str_number] ?>" rel=”nofollow”>
                                    <a class="card-title"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapse<?php echo $enum_of_collapsible_str_numbers[$collapsible_str_number] ?>" class="card-body collapse"
                                     data-parent="#accordion">
                                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                                </div>

                            <?php }
                        }
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                        ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you can use numerical values for `enum_of_collapsible_numbers` and you can generate them like this

```
$enum_of_collapsible_numbers = range(1, 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally do not prefer the mixing of data collection with data printing, but I understand that this is common on simple Wordpress pages (I am not a Wordpress developer).

`id` values do not need to be purely comprised of letters to be valid, so I would use a counter and scrap the idea of having a limited-length lookup array of words.

Using `printf()` will help to clean up your code by removing string concatenation/interpolation; it also allows you to reuse the same variable in the same expression.  Generally, I don't enjoy trying to read a bunch of `<?php ... ?>` declarations bouncing in and out of php in script -- it just feels too noisy.

Move your `cursor:pointer;` inline declaration to an external stylesheet inside `.collapsed{}` to reduce some of the eye strain on this script.

Consider declaring your `<div>` attributes on multiple lines to prevent excessively long lines of code.

Do not use (multibyte) curly quotes to encapsulate attribute values.

I think I recommend writing `<a>` inside of `<h2>` instead of the inverse.

Untested suggestion:

```
$wv_services = new WP_Query([
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'service',
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'ASC'
]);

while ($wv_services->have_posts()) {
    $post_count = wp_count_posts('service')->publish;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $post_count; ++$i) {
        $wv_services->the_post();
        sprintf('
            <div class="card-header collapsed"
                 data-toggle="collapse"
                 href="#collapse%1$d"
                 rel="nofollow"
            >
                <h2>
                    <a class="card-title">%2$s</a>
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse%1$d"
                 class="card-body collapse"
                 data-parent="#accordion"
            >
                <p>%3$s</p>
            </div>',
            $i,             // referenced by %1$d
            the_title(),    // referenced by %2$s
            the_content()   // referenced by %3$s
        );
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```